# Selenium stuck loading frame with basic authentication

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, frame, basic-authentication

I'm using selenium in python to check the page of a website that uses basic authentication on one frame. I'm checking to see if the password I am entering is correct or not, so the basic authentication often gets stuck because the password is wrong. Normally I use sel.set_page_load_timeout(8) and then catch the exception thrown when the page takes too long, but because the page loads except for the one frame, this function is not throwing an exception, and the page is getting stuck. How can I break out of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: go to the url of the frame itself, and set page load timeout on that page